Hide Webpack in Web Browser Sources
I am having a problem with an Angular project in version 8.2.14 and that is when I compile it in production and upload it to the server. I access the website, if you inspect the Soruces of the web browser, webpack:// appears and inside all the code of the web application.
This does not happen to me in other more recent Angular projects and I don't know the reason or what I should configure or do so that webpack does not appear in the browser. More than anything for not showing the web application code...
I have looked for different configurations within angular.json but I have not been able to solve the problem of hiding webpack from the sources. Maybe that's not the problem or I simply haven't known how to configure it correctly.

You can't hide the FE code. You can make it harder to reach / read by - for example - not compiling the source map for production environments, but that's it.

As the comment above says, set "sourceMap": false on your production build. Additionally, set "optimization": true. I believe this will obfuscate the js files.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
